# Asus AC55 (AC-1300) WiFi Adapter

Tags: wireless, drivers, asus

I am having trouble finding any drivers for the Asus AC55r WiFi Adapter. It is using AC-1300 Wireless and the USB ID is 0b05:17eb.

Answer (score 3):

This question is the only meaningful mention I can find about this usb.id 0b05:17eb. I am unable to find any Linux driver for the device. We might then consider ndiswrapper, the package that uses Windows XP driver files. I checked on the Asus site and they only offer Windows 7 and 8 driver packages. ndiswrapper will not work with 7 or 8 drivers.

I regret that there is no method I can find to get your device working.